# How to match the expression with different patterns

Tags: regex, splunk

I need to match following patterns to extract type of files.

```
some text here ../../file/path/dir/200.FILETYPE.234234.20150404_092222.xml and some text
some random text here ../../file/path/dir/FILETYPE.345223.SOMETEXT.20150404_092222.xml and some other text
```

Tried this to extract the file type

```
".*\/dir\/(?<importfiletype>.*)\..*\..*\..*\.xml
```

but it selects FILETYPE.345223 in the field extracted instead of just FILETYPE. It extracts FILETYPE correctly as there are only 3 dots before xml. Any help is appreciated.

Note: FILETYPE can be any word like jpg, png etc.

Example paths:
../../file/path/dir/jpg.345223.SOMETEXT.20150404_092222.xml
../../file/path/dir/200.jpg.3235223.SOMETEXT.20150404_092222.something.xml 
../../file/path/dir/png.SOMETEXT.SOMETEXT.20150404_092222.xml

after png or jpg and before there can be 3 or 4 dots

Comment: its working correctly as per your regex :- https://regex101.com/r/uH1iA1/1

but still its not clear, what  you want?

Comment: well it selects "200" and "ANOTHERFILETYPE", respectively.

Comment: @rock321987 if you see two lines of raw data.. one line has 3 dots before xml string and other has four dots. So 3 dots match in each case but I get ANOTHERFILETYPE.345223 instead of ANOTHERFILETYPE in the second case. I made a test to show you what is the issue https://regex101.com/r/fM5wT2/1 . I need only ANOTHERFILETYPE  or anything before it i.e. 200.TYPEXFILETYPE in first line,  ANOTHERFILETYPE   in second line

Comment: Number of dots `200.TYPEXFILETYPE.234234.20150404_092222.xml` = 4

Number of dots `ANOTHERFILETYPE.345223.SOMETEXT.20150404_092222.xml` = 4

How are you saying number of dots are different?

Comment: @rock321987 I am counting after TYPEXFILETYPE only not before that word. I need entire characters after / and TYPEXFILETYPE. (TYPEXFILETYPE is any word including dots)

Comment: what do you want to extract from those two strings exactly because your pattern is not at all consistent to me?

Comment: @rock321987, please see output in https://regex101.com/r/fM5wT2/1 . the second match contain .345223 which I do not want. Hope I am clear now

Comment: You want `200.TYPEXFILETYPE` in first output?

Comment: Yes I need everything before filetype including filetype but not after that. filetype can be any string like 200.jpeg, png, file10 etc.

Comment: I can't hardcode as FILETYPE, it can be any string, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Let me modify it..

Comment: just tell me one thing:- there should be a name present at least before FILETYPE which is not present in 2nd string

Comment: I updated my op. the filetype is any string which can have prefix of one word+dot or nothing. for example dir/200.jpg.*.xml, dir/jpg.*.xml, dir/png.*.xml are some example paths

Comment: Do you know all possible file extension, because it seems impossible to do without it? just think yourself how will you know anything after `/` is filetype or name

Comment: Yes, it is only xml extension as you can see in my comments

Comment: I am asking about `jpg` extension etc?

Comment: no. that string can be any word :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
^.* (.*\/dir\/[^\.]*)\.([^ ]*).*$
```

Group 1 is path+filename, Group 2 is the filetype (everything after first dot unto next blank)